# STM32 multiple addresses and .bin files

Tags: stm32, stm32cubeide

I have situation where I need to flash two BIN files to different addresses on an STM32.

For example: the first file goes to 0x08000000, and the other goes to 0x08080000. Is there any way to do tbus using the command line, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command line interface of [STM32CubeProgrammer](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stm32cubeprog.html):

```
STM32_Programmer_CLI.exe -c port=SWD -d Firmware.bin 0x08000000
```

Read the [manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/um2237-stm32cubeprogrammer-software-description-stmicroelectronics.pdf) for more details.

Comment: At [your link](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stm32cubeprog.html) I have found the graphical program `STM32CubeProrgammer`, without the command line interface `STM32_Programmer_CLI.exe`.

Comment: @frankfalse the CLI program is installed with the graphical program.

Comment: Thank you very much. `STM32_Programmer_CLI.exe` has been installed in a folder that is not in my PATH variable (on Windows). I have added that folder to my PATH and now I can execute `STM32_Programmer_CLI.exe` that evidently has been installed with the Graphical program